# Why are the row space and column space lattices of a boolean matrix inverses of each other?

Tags: abstract-algebra, boolean-algebra, vector-lattices

We define the row/column space of a matrix $A$ to be all possible sums of rows/columns of $A$.

The row space ($V(A)$) and column space ($W(A)$) form a lattice.

See example matrix and respective row space lattice here:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1&0\\0&1&0&1&\\0&0&1&1&\\0&1&0&0\end{bmatrix}\to \langle V(A);\land,\lor\rangle,$$ where $\langle V(A);\land,\lor\rangle=$

[image]

and the example matrix and respective column space lattice here:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1&0\\0&1&0&1\\0&0&1&1\\0&1&0&0\end{bmatrix}\to \langle W(A);\land,\lor\rangle,$$ where $\langle W(A);\land,\lor\rangle=$

[image]

All row and column space lattices are inverses of each other. Any ideas on a proof to this?

Comment: I was unable to make the diagrams using latex code. As a result I had to put images there. If anyone knows how to do these complex diagrams using latex codes please let me know.

Comment: I am trying to understand your last sentence.  When you say these "lattices are inverses of each other" do you just mean that $V(A)$ and $W(A)$ are isomorphic lattices? (i.e. That there is always an invertible mapping from $V(A)$ to $W(A)$ that preserves the lattice structure.)